# Recieving undefined from Javascript $.post

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

I am writing a web application that will allow me to control a lgWebOS Smart TV from a control panel. I have a server set up with Node.js and Express, which when requested for '/' will return a basic HTML file with an input area to change the volume. I want to be able to send the data in the text/input box back to my server to pass on to the lgTV. Code:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximux-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>lgWebOS App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/stylesheet">
      h1{
        font-family: fantasy;
        color: black;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var vol;
        $('#volSubmit').on('click', function(){
          vol = $("#volVal").val();
          $.post("http://localhost:3000/volume",
          {volVal: vol}, function(data){
            if(data==='done'){
              alert('Volume Changed');
            }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="container col-md-12">
        <h1 id="title" style="text-align:center;">LGwebOS Application</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="volume col-md-6">
        <h3>Set Volume Here</h3>
        <input type="text" id="volVal" value="3">
        <input type="button" id="volSubmit" value="Set">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**SERVER/NODE.JS:**

```
module.exports = {
  config: expressConfig,
  getHome: getHome,
  post: volPost,
  start: runServer
}

var lgtv = require('./webOS.js')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

function expressConfig(){
  lgtv.config();
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    res.header('Expires', '-1');
    res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
    next();
  });
  app.set('views', __dirname = './views');
  app.set('views engine', 'ejs');
  app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
}

function getHome(){
  app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.html');
  });
}

function volPost(){
  app.post('/volume', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    var level = req.body.volVal;
    console.log(level);
    lgtv.setVol(level);
  });
}

function runServer(){
  var server = app.listen(3000, function(err){
    if(err){
      console.log('An error occred: ' + err);
    }
    console.log('Web server is running on localhost port 3000');
  });
}
```

There in the server file, in my volPost function,  I have it set to log the variable 'level' and the request body. The variable level is supposed to be the data sent along from the HTML, but it returns as undefined, the request body returns as an empty JS object.

Comment: You do not return anything....

Comment: @epascarello I've changed the title, does that make more sense?

Comment: yes, it makes sense. You should return response for client to show `alert`.  Also, `expressConfig` should defined before `volPost`.

Comment: in node, on `volPost`, you'll need to send a response back, something like `response.send('done')`. otherwise your browser will never know something happened on your server